# Cliver::Dependency::NotFound:Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path. error on Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am getting this error while building the project on Jenkins . The execution is running hassle free on my local machine . I have added these to my Gemfile .

```
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'phantomjs'
```

The error only occurs on jenkins.
using phantomjs 2.1.1.0

Answer (score 4):

if you're using Rails' system tests, you'll need to pass proper options to the driver to have it use PhantomJS from the `phantomjs` gem:

```
require 'phantomjs'

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :poltergeist, options: { phantomjs: Phantomjs.path }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From the phantomjs gem readme, you need to do

```
gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
```

to configure the poltergeist driver automatically - https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem#usage-with-poltergeistcapybara - or specify the PhantomJS location if manually registering the poltergeist driver - https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem#manual-setup .  This is because the phantomjs gem doesn't install the binary into the PATH, so 
 Poltergeist needs to be told where it is.  On your local machine it's probably finding another install of PhantomJS that is in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This script install PhantomJS in your Debian/Ubuntu System
#
# This script must be run as root:
# sudo sh install_phantomjs.sh
#

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

PHANTOM_VERSION="phantomjs-2.1.1"
ARCH=$(uname -m)

if ! [ $ARCH = "x86_64" ]; then
    $ARCH="i686"
fi

PHANTOM_JS="$PHANTOM_VERSION-linux-$ARCH"

apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev -y
apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev -y
apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev -y

cd ~
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/$PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2
tar xvjf $PHANTOM_JS.tar.bz2

mv $PHANTOM_JS /usr/local/share
ln -sf /usr/local/share/$PHANTOM_JS/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
```

Give the file executable permissions

```
chmod +x install_phantomjs.sh
```

Then push to git to rebuild

```
git add install_phantomjs.sh
git commit -m 'Install PhantomJS'
git push
```

NB: Find the latest PhantomJS versions here https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/, then you can edit the `PHANTOM_VERSION` env variable appropriately